Html <div> leaves unexpected margins
I am new to HTML and CSS. I was experimenting with displaying <div> -s side by side. I noticed that simply adding a div inside the body will display with unexpected margins.
I tried messing about with margin, border and padding properties in my css file but nothing seems to work. the div leaves a gap to every side of the page, please help, I don't know how to get rid of it.
The HTML:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#box1 {
  background-color: grey;
}

#box2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div id="box1" class="box">
      <p>Some text in box 1.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="box2" class="box">
      <p>Some text in box 1.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




As others have noted, all you need to do is to assign a margin to the body tag.  As you are beginning, you should start to get familiar with developer tools.  There are many handy tools here, one of which is the elements tab.  As this isn't going to be the first time you are wondering why an element is behaving a certain way, you should get familiar.  Take your original post, open Developer Tools, select the Elements tab, and hover over your image.  Right there, you will see the defecto margin that was applied to your page

Another option would be to set the box positions to absolute (as in this answer)


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#box1 {
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

#box2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0px;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div id="box1" class="box">
      <p>Some text in box 1.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="box2" class="box">
      <p>Some text in box 1.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Just curious why position: absolute, which may throw some issues for responsive design, instead of * { margin: 0, padding: 0; }

I think using * { margin: 0, padding: 0; } is a better way of doing it, but this is just something that works in the particular situation that the OP is describing. I'm surprised this is the accepted answer, but will upvote the others myself!

You can clear the margin and padding by adding styles to the html and body tags:
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

Another common fix would be to use a CSS reset.
I updated your code snippet:


html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#box1 {
  background-color: grey;
}

#box2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div id="box1" class="box">
      <p>Some text in box 1.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="box2" class="box">
      <p>Some text in box 1.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Thank you! So the body has some margin and padding by default? I will defenetly read the linked article aswell.

Yes, all sorts of elements will have default styles...that's why it's a common practice to use a css reset

Got it! Thank you.



* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#box1 {
  background-color: grey;
}

#box2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div id="box1" class="box">
      <p>Some text in box 1.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="box2" class="box">
      <p>Some text in box 1.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



